# Is there a way to freeze python code only partially?

Tags: python, windows, software-distribution

I would like to distribute my python application to the end-user as single-file executable. However, the end-user has the possibility to add functionalities to the application. For this he can write funtions to a python file which is then imported at runtime.
However, if I freeze the Application for distribution, any changes made by the user to the python file afterwards will have no effect.

How can I distribute my Application as a more or less single-file executable to the end-user with him still being able to add/remove functions?

Or can you give the user the possibility to add functionality in another way than by importing his Python functions at runtime?

Comment: Do you need it to be an executable? Or would you be fine with the user running a python script from console?

Comment: I would prefer it to be an executable. The goal would be that the user does not necessarily have to have Python installed on his system if he just wants to use the tool.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach What would the python script, that the user had to run from console, look like?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a misunderstanding of how a programme written in Python is actually executed. If we want to "import Python code at runtime" into a programme, this imported Python code would have to be compiled at runtime. If the end-user does not have a Python compiler installed, how should that be possible? Unless your programme effectively contains a Python compiler, I think, what you want to achieve is impossible by design.

Comment: Would it make sense to include a Python compiler in the distribution of the programm? Or would you say I'd be better to simply have the end-user install python seperatly? And thank you for the explanation!

Comment: @NicolasBrauer I think it is way easier to have the end user install python separately. I think writing a Python compiler in Python is a pretty expensive thing.